# NullPointer Error on running uiautomator test case on emulator

Tags: android, android-uiautomator

I succeeded running my first uiautomator test case in emulator, and everything goes fine. But when I started the same test case second time in the same emulator. I got this error:

```
INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: stack=java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.android.uiautomator.core.ShellUiAutomatorBridge.getDefaultDisplay(ShellUiAutomatorBridge.java:50)
at com.android.uiautomator.core.UiDevice.getDisplayWidth(UiDevice.java:378)
at com.android.uiautomator.core.UiDevice.click(UiDevice.java:408)
at test.uiautomator.ApiTest.testCase(ApiTest.java:172)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at com.android.uiautomator.testrunner.UiAutomatorTestRunner.start(UiAutomatorTestRunner.java:160)
at com.android.uiautomator.testrunner.UiAutomatorTestRunner.run(UiAutomatorTestRunner.java:96)
at com.android.commands.uiautomator.RunTestCommand.run(RunTestCommand.java:91)
at com.android.commands.uiautomator.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:83)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.nativeFinishInit(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.main(RuntimeInit.java:243)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Does any one knows the reason? I did not modify any line in the test case, I just ran it for the second time.

Comment: Please post your code that the error is referencing, so that we can see where the issue might be,

Answer (score 0):

I checked the code , error occur here:

```
public Display getDefaultDisplay() {
    return  DisplayManagerGlobal.getInstance().getRealDisplay(Display.DEFAULT_DISPLAY);// Nullpointer here. 
}
```

It may becasue DisplayManagerGlobal.getInstance() returned NULL.

see code :

```
/**
 * Gets an instance of the display manager global singleton.
 *
 * @return The display manager instance, may be null early in system startup
 * before the display manager has been fully initialized.
 */
public static DisplayManagerGlobal getInstance() {
    synchronized (DisplayManagerGlobal.class) {
        if (sInstance == null) {
            IBinder b = ServiceManager.getService(Context.DISPLAY_SERVICE);
            if (b != null) {
                sInstance = new DisplayManagerGlobal(IDisplayManager.Stub.asInterface(b));
            }
        }
        return sInstance;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hej, thanks for your help. I also checked here, but the question is how come this function returned null?

Comment: Why do you use DisplayManagerGlobal instead of UiDevice?